# Count the number of cells with in a date range

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count how many cells with dates in them that are within in a date range.

I have dates in column G in a tab and then I have 2 cells in another tab that makes the range.

The daterange contains these formulas. `=Now()` and the other is `=Now+7`.

I have been googling around for a answer but the ones that I found seems to have a "fixed date" for the date range and that is not what I'm looking for here.

Looking forward for some help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a simple `COUNTIFS` formula.

If the criteria for the date range are in B1,`=NOW()`, and B2, `=NOW()+7`, on Sheet2 you could use this formula on the sheet with the dates in column G.

```
=COUNTIFS(G2:G21, ">="&Sheet2!B1, G2:G21,"<="&Sheet2!B2)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=COUNTIFS(G:G; ">="&NOW(); G:G; "<"&NOW()+8)
```